# Speeding up calculation of symmetric matrices; use of outer

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I need to speed up a calculation that produces a symmetric matrix. Currently I have something like this:

> ```
> X <- 1:50
> Y<- 1:50
> M <- outer(X, Y, FUN = myfun)
> ```

where myfun is a quite complicated, vectorized, but symmetrical function (myfun(x, y) = myfun(y, x)).

So my code unnecessarily wastes time calculating the lower triangular matrix as well as the upper triangular matrix.

How can I avoid that duplication without using slow for-loops?

Comment: This is not related directly to your question but I trust it will help - [the R open distribution from Microsoft](https://mran.microsoft.com/open)  uses multi-threaded math libraries - Intel MKL which gives a significant boost to matrix operations (over 100x speed up is some situations) compared to single threaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries. I found it is well worth the effort to install it.

Comment: How can M be a symmetric matrix when it is not square?

Comment: One way would be to use memoisation and use a wrapper to ensure that when `myfun(y,x)` is called it looks for `myfun(x,y)`. This might be useful: https://github.com/r-lib/memoise

Comment: @989 Not necessarily; I just used integers to illustrate the question.

Comment: @989 The function is of the form Vectorize(fn(x, y)). fn takes two scalars and returns a scalar.

Comment: @James I had not heard of memoise, so thanks for that.

Comment: `Vectorize` is syntactic sugar that hides a loop. You should never use it if speed is an issue.

Comment: I am using Vectorize because the underlying scalar function is integrate, which returns a scalar with no option for anything else so far as I can see.

Comment: @Roland I forgot to add your name to my comment above.

Comment: I would use a foreach loop instead of the Vectorize loop and parallelize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is slow and timing scales with size of its input, you could use `combn`:

```
X <- 1:50
Y <- 1:50

#a slow function
myfun <- function(x, y) {
  res <- x * NA
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    Sys.sleep(0.01)
    res[i] <- x[i] * y[i]
    }
  res
}

system.time(M <- outer(X, Y, FUN = myfun))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.00    0.00   26.41 

system.time({
  inds <- combn(seq_len(length(X)), 2)
  M1 <- matrix(ncol = length(X), nrow = length(Y))

  M1[lower.tri(M1)] <-  myfun(X[inds[1,]], Y[inds[2,]])
  M1[upper.tri(M1)] <- t(M1)[upper.tri(M1)]
  diag(M1) <- myfun(X, Y)
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.00    0.00   13.41

all.equal(M, M1)
#[1] TRUE
```

However, the best solution is probably to implement this in C++ via Rcpp.

Comment: Many thanks. I can't write C++ but halving the time with your R code is well worthwhile.

Comment: Maybe `seq_along(X)` in place of `seq_len(length(X))`?

Comment: Sure. Doesn't make a difference speed-wise here, though.