# Outer in R but only get upper matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

If you type `outer(x, x, f)`, you get a matrix with elements `f(x(i), x(j))` for every element in the vector `x`.

How do I do the same thing, but where I only want the upper triangular matrix part of this same matrix?

Obviously I can use `outer` and then extract the upper triangular matrix, but I don't need everything else, so it seems pointless to calculate it.

Basically, I want the upper triangular matrix where element `i, j` for `j >= i` is `f(x(i), x(j))`, and I want it in the fastest way possible.

Comment: This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52384294/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `upper.tri` from `base R` to create a logical matrix and subset the elements

```
out <- outer(x, x, f)
out[upper.tri(out)]
```

---

Instead of using `outer`, this can be done with `combn`

```
combn(x, 2, FUN = f)
```

Also, for a fast option,

```
arrangements::combinations(x, k = 2)
```

can return the combinations and then apply the 'f' on those

Comment: The second option using `arrangements` is really fast. Thank you.